$B(3,3), C(2,3)$ Magma notation
When one asks for composition factors of groups, Magma sometimes gives notations like $B(3,3), C(2,3), 2A(3,3)$. What are these? Are they groups of Lie type? I did some searching but just couldn't get an answer.
Thank you.

https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/handbook/text/647

many many thx!!

This is Lie type notation, but an  alternative notation is also included, which is helpful for identify them. For example $C(3,5)$ is also named as $S(6,5)$, which is the simple group ${\rm PSp}(6,5)$.

I see. Thank you very much!
